# Как в Reacte js добавить полю input дополнительно список возможных адресов

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно сделать поле инпут в которое можно в водить адрес, после чего у меня отправляется запрос на яндекс апи карт и возвращается список адресов, при клики на который данные будут переданы в input и зафиксированы.

В официальной документации https://ru.react.js.org/docs/forms.html есть вариант как сделать просто список, но в поле я не могу  в вести адрес, поскольку список стал фиксированный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае логика довольно проста:

- Создайте ваш input.
- Храните его value в каком либо состоянии, к примеру используя хук [useState()](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).
- Создайте функцию-обработчик, которая будет реагировать на событие onChange вашего input, изменяя состояние, созданное с помощью useState() на value, что будет получено этой функцией.
- Передайте её в атрибут onChange вашего input.

Готово. Вы создали свой [управляемый компонент](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Теперь вы можете использовать значение, хранимое в состоянии для ваших нужд (к примеру запросов на сервер, etc.).

Для создания сложных форм рекомендую использовать вспомогательные библиотеки, к примеру [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но я уже сам нашел решение.